# What do these lines of code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, strikethrough

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to program a to-do list in Javascript and am experimenting with JQuery. I found a strikethrough animation online that I wanted to implement into the list but I am not quite sure what these two lines of code do and was wondering if someone could elaborate for me so I can better understand? The strikethrough function is as follows:

```
//var _Text sets the _Text to the individual list item
var _text = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId); 
$(document).ready(function() {
_text = $(itemText).text();
StrikeThrough(0);
});
//Strikethrough animation function
function StrikeThrough(index) {
    if (index >= _text.length)
        return false;
    var sToStrike = _text.substr(0, index + 1);
    var sAfter = (index < (_text.length - 1)) ? _text.substr(index + 1, 
_text.length - index) : "";
    $(itemText).html("<strike>" + sToStrike + "</strike>" + sAfter);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        StrikeThrough(index + 1);
    }, 100);
```

The two lines that I'm confused about are:

```
var sToStrike = _text.substr(0, index + 1);
var sAfter = (index < (_text.length - 1)) ? _text.substr(index + 1, _text.length - index) : "";
```

What I am specifically confused about is what these variables are being set to exactly

Comment: The first line calls [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) which is used to get a portion of a string. The second line is a [`ternary expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is a condensed `if` condition.

Comment: Sometimes the best way to understand code is to use a JS debugger, e.g., put a `debugger` statement before the lines in question, then experiment in the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

`sToStrike` is set to a text from beginning to the next character of current index position
`sAfter` is set the rest of the string if the index is not already the last character

Answer (score 0):

This line assigns `sToStrike` a substring of `_text` from index `0` to index `index + 1`:

```
var sToStrike = _text.substr(0, index + 1);
```

This line contains a ternary expression, which is an inline if/else. It assigns `sAfter` either a substring of `_text` from index `index + 1` to index `_text.length - index` or an empty string `""` dependent on `index < (_text.length-1)` evaluating to True or False, in their respective order:

```
var sAfter = (index < (_text.length - 1)) ? _text.substr(index + 1,_text.length - index) : "";
```